# HTML/CSS: Keeping Elements Positioned with Window Change

Tags: html, css, blackberry-webworks

I'm very new to CSS and I spend quite a while trying to research how to position elements "in thirds" so that even when the window changes dimensions the elements stay "in thirds". The first picture below is when the browser is fully opened and the second is when it is horizontally contracted. I am looking for this method but I don't know the name of the technique or what to do (like I said I'm really new). I'm aware that the tabs are using what is called "closing doors" but I'm more interested in their positioning.

[image]

[image]

For example if I wanted three elements spaced out unevenly
to contract as follows, how would I go above achieving this?

[image]

instead of:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this solution. This is flexible and if more menu comes it will accommodate it automatically.

http://jsfiddle.net/geymU/

```
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Address</li>
    <li>Phone</li>
  </ul>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
#nav{
   background:#c1c1c1;
}
#nav ul{
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}
#nav li{
  padding:5px;
  display:table-cell;
  background:#333;
  border:1px solid;
  color:#fff;
}​
```

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing actual code, I would recommend that you declare your horizontal widths, margins and padding with **relative** units. That would be % or ems, not pixels.

So, in your example,

```
 #element_2 {
     margin-left: 45%;
  }
  #element_3 {
     margin-left: 5%;
  }
```

With relative units, you will have to do a little more trial-and-error to get elements to place how you want.

Answer (score 0):

In your pictures it looks like the backgroundimage (i assume it's an image, since it doesnt stretch over the whole button) is only lacking a

```
background-repeat: repeat-x;
```

However what I see in your second example can be easily archived if you set the first button to

```
    float: left;
```

and the remaining buttons to

```
    float: right;
```

Just don't forget to

```
    clear: both;
```

after them, incase you don't have any more elements removed from the document flow (which is what float does).